# How to add a role dependency outside of galaxy?

Tags: dependencies, ansible, ansible-role

I'm creating a company set of Ansible roles. One of them relies upon another.

All of these roles are hosted on their specific Gitlab repositories (one per role, obviously).

Instead of messing up with `requirements.yml`, I do prefer to use the `dependencies` tag of my `meta/main.yml` file. But I can't find which syntax use to create dependency links without declare them in Ansible galaxy (which is obviously impossible).

How can I do that ?

Comment: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20537?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it but according to Ansible-Galaxy documentation [about dependencies](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/galaxy.html#dependencies), it seems that:

> You specify role dependencies in the `meta/main.yml` file by providing a
>   list of roles. If the source of a role is Galaxy, you can simply
>   specify the role in the format `username.role_name`. The more complex
>   format used in `requirements.yml` is also supported, allowing you to
>   provide `src`, `scm`, `version`, and `name`.

And an example follows:

```
dependencies:
  - src: geerlingguy.ansible
  - src: git+https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-composer.git
    version: 775396299f2da1f519f0d8885022ca2d6ee80ee8
    name: composer
```